# How can I specify which Python toolchain to use in Bazel?

Tags: python, build, bazel

How can I configure Bazel to pick one toolchain over the other? I am okay with defining which toolchain to use via command-line argument or specifying which should be used in a specific target.

There are currently two toolchains being defined in my WORKSPACE file. I have two Python toolchains. One of them builds Python from source and includes it in the executable `.zip` output, and the other one does not.

When building, the toolchain that gets used is always the first toolchain which is registered. In this case, `python3_tooolchain` is used even though the build target imports `requirement` from `hermetic_python3_toolchain`.

```
# WORKSPACE

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_install")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/download/0.5.0/rules_python-0.5.0.tar.gz",
    sha256 = "cd6730ed53a002c56ce4e2f396ba3b3be262fd7cb68339f0377a45e8227fe332",
)

# Non-hermetic toolchain 
register_toolchains("//src:python3_toolchain")

pip_install(
   quiet = False,
   name = "python_dependencies",
   requirements = "//:requirements.txt",
   python_interpreter = "/usr/bin/python3"
)

load("@python_dependencies//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")




# Hermetic toolchain 

_py_configure = """
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
    ./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/bazel_install --with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)
else
    ./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/bazel_install
fi
"""

http_archive(
    name = "hermetic_interpreter",
    urls = ["https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/Python-3.11.0.tar.xz"],
    sha256 = "a57dc82d77358617ba65b9841cee1e3b441f386c3789ddc0676eca077f2951c3",
    strip_prefix = "Python-3.11.0",
    patch_cmds = [
        "mkdir $(pwd)/bazel_install",
        _py_configure,
        "make",
        "make install",
        "ln -s bazel_install/bin/python3 python_bin",
    ],
    build_file_content = """
exports_files(["python_bin"])
filegroup(
    name = "files",
    srcs = glob(["bazel_install/**"], exclude = ["**/* *"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)

pip_install(
    name = "hermetic_python3_dependencies",
    requirements = "//:requirements.txt",
    python_interpreter_target = "@hermetic_interpreter//:python_bin",
)
load("@hermetic_python3_dependencies//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")




load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_binary")
load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_library")

register_toolchains("//src:hermetic_python3_toolchain")
```

```
# src/BUILD

load("@bazel_tools//tools/python:toolchain.bzl", "py_runtime_pair")

# Non-hermetic toolchain 
py_runtime(
    name = "python3_runtime",
    interpreter_path = "/usr/bin/python3",
    python_version = "PY3",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

py_runtime_pair(
    name = "python3_runtime_pair",
    py2_runtime = None,
    py3_runtime = ":python3_runtime",
)

toolchain(
    name = "python3_toolchain",
    toolchain = ":python3_runtime_pair",
    toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/python:toolchain_type",
)

# Hermetic toolchain

py_runtime(
    name = "hermetic_python3_runtime",
    files = ["@hermetic_interpreter//:files"],
    interpreter = "@hermetic_interpreter//:python_bin",
    python_version = "PY3",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

py_runtime_pair(
    name = "hermetic_python3_runtime_pair",
    py2_runtime = None,
    py3_runtime = ":hermetic_python3_runtime",
)

toolchain(
    name = "hermetic_python3_toolchain",
    toolchain = ":hermetic_python3_runtime_pair",
    toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/python:toolchain_type",
)


package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
```

```
# /src/some_tool/BUILD

load("@hermetic_python3_dependencies//:requirements.bzl", "requirement") # Can load this rule from either `hermetic_python3_dependencies` or `python3_dependencies`, but does not seem to make a difference 

py_binary(
    name = "some-tool",
    main = "some_tool.py",
    srcs = ["some_tool_file.py"],
    python_version = "PY3",
    srcs_version = "PY3",
    deps = [
        requirement("requests"),
        "//src/common/some-library:library",
    ]
)

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It can be done by [registering](https://bazel.build/extending/toolchains#registering-building-toolchains)  the toolchain, either in a WORKSPACE file using register_toolchains(), or by passing the toolchains' labels on the command line using the --extra_toolchains flag.

Comment: I'm already registering the toolchains in the WORKSPACE... some builds need to be hermetic (those builds need to build a Python interpreter from source and include it in the build), but other builds can use the system interpreter. How do I specify which toolchain to use after they are both registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider upgrading `rules_python`, as that ruleset includes a hermetic python toolchain since https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/tag/0.7.0.

If that is not an option:

Currently you are registering two toolchains in your `WORKSPACE.bazel` file and `bazel` will use its [toolchain resolution](https://bazel.build/extending/toolchains#toolchain-resolution) to pick one of them. You can debug that resolution with the `--toolchain_resolution_debug=regex` flag to see what is going on.

If you want to force the entire build to use one of the toolchains, remove registering the toolchains from the `WORKSPACE.bazel` file and create a `.bazelrc`:

```
build:hermetic_python --extra_toolchains=//src:hermetic_python3_toolchain
build:system_python --extra_toolchains=//src:python3_toolchain
```

Now you can switch between these toolchains by using `bazel build --config=hermetic_python` or `bazel build --config=system_python`.

Beware however, that this does not influence which of the python toolchains was used to run the `pip_parse()`. You need to take extra care from which you load the `requirement()` function. Simply by `load()`ing the function you force the evaluation of the `pip_parse()` and therefor the fetching/compilation of the corresponding python interpreter.